# Azure : How to write path to get a file from a time series partitioned folder using the Azure logic apps

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-logic-apps, azure-storage-explorer

I am trying to retrieve a csv file from the Azure blob storage using the logic apps.
I set the azure storage explorer path in the parameters and in the get blob content action I am using that parameter.
[image: Parameter Screenshot]

In the Parameters I have set the value as:

```
concat('Directory1/','Year=',string(int(substring(utcNow(),0,4))),'/Month=',string(int(substring(utcnow(),5,2))),'/Day=',string(int(substring(utcnow(),8,2))),'/myfile.csv')
```

So during the run time this path should form as:

```
Directory1/Year=2019/Month=12/Day=30/myfile.csv
```

but during the execution action is getting failed with the following error message

```
{
  "status": 400,
  "message": "The specifed resource name contains invalid characters.\r\nclientRequestId: 1e2791be-8efd-413d-831e-7e2cd89278ba",
  "error": {
    "message": "The specifed resource name contains invalid characters."
  },
  "source": "azureblob-we.azconn-we-01.p.azurewebsites.net"
}
```

So my question is: How to write path to get data from the time series partitioned path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use that in the parameters, when you use this line `concat('Directory1/','Year=',string(int(substring(utcNow(),0,4))),'/Month=',string(int(substring(utcnow(),5,2))),'/Day=',string(int(substring(utcnow(),8,2))),'/myfile.csv')` in the parameters, its type is `String`, it will be recognized as `String` by logic app, then the function will not take effect.

And you need to include the container name in the `concat()`, also, no need to use `string(int())`, because `utcNow()` and `substring()` both return the `String`.

To fix the issue, use the line below directly in the `Blob` option, my container name is `container1`.

```
concat('container1/','Directory1/','Year=',substring(utcNow(),0,4),'/Month=',substring(utcnow(),5,2),'/Day=',substring(utcnow(),8,2),'/myfile.csv')
```

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

As mentioned in @Stark's answer, if you want to drop the leading 0 from the left.

You can convert it from string to int, then convert it back to string.

```
concat('container1/','Directory1/','Year=',string(int(substring(utcNow(),0,4))),'/Month=',string(int(substring(utcnow(),5,2))),'/Day=',string(int(substring(utcnow(),8,2))),'/myfile.csv')
```

Comment: Though the file exist in the directory but it is unable to get it. The possible reason may be-
My Blob directory structure is: container1/Directory1/Year=2020/Month=1/Day=1/myfile.csv
The Directory Structure is created by LA is : container1/Directory1/Year=2020/Month=01/Day=01/myfile.csv
So due to Zero '0' with the month number and Day it is looking for the file in diffrent directory.

Comment: How do I exclude the extra Zero '0' from the path?

Comment: @Stark I think you should modify your blob directory name instead of the logic app expression, if you use the function like substring() to move the ‘0’, then it will affect the normal date without ‘0’, it will not work. There is no function to exclude the zero directly currently.

Comment: You are correct!! I am making some change in source code and once I validate the solution then I'll accept it. Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: please check my solution.

Comment: @Starks How is it different from mine? Convert it from string to int, then convert it back to string with string(int())? as I mentioned, no need to use string(int()), because utcNow() and substring() both return the String.

Comment: when we are converting string to int it will drop the leading 0 from the left.

Comment: and during the runtime it will look for the folders having the structure as 2019/01/01/myfile.csv. While the correct path is 2019/1/1/myfile.csv

Answer (score 1):

The response of the Joy Wang was partially correct.
The **Parameters** in logic apps will treat values as a String only and will not be able to identify any functions such as concat().
The correct way to use the concat function is to use the expressions.

[image: expression screenshot]
And my solution to the problem is:

```
concat('container1/','Directory1/','Year=',string(int(substring(utcNow(),0,4))),'/Month=',string(int(substring(utcnow(),5,2))),'/Day=',string(int(substring(utcnow(),8,2))),'/myfile.csv')
```